# Passing JWT token in headers in Thymeleaf and Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, authorization, spring-thymeleaf

I want to pass a JWT token as an `Authorization` header with my requests, but I'm using Thymeleaf and Spring Security intercepts the requests before I my controller can add the headers in the `HttpResponse`. How can I pass the token with every request?

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain config(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                 .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/css/**","/scss/**","/vendor/**","/img/**","/js/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth","register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .formLogin(form -> form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                                .permitAll()
                 )
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

My controller for the `POST` request to `/login`

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView processLogin(HttpServletResponse res) {
        String jwttoken="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkZXkiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODMxNzkxODMsImV4cCI6MTY4MzI2NTU4M30.3-_7VrfDg91TUKvHh18JIclt-NTmcx9UnZnsNMoCKyA";
        res.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer "+ jwttoken);

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login");
        return mv;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to add headers in your controller? That should be done with Spring Security. However, why can't you add your token in your controller? It should be possible. Show your Spring Security configuration and your controller implementation.

Comment: @dur I've edited the post above. I've hardcoded my token to check if it works but when debugging my request in the browser, the token isn't present in the headers. When doing it with postman everything works fine. I'm open to any suggestions on what I should read about so I can actually access different pages with auth. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK `Authenthitcation` header is only used in requests, not responses. Maybe the browser checks it. Try to use another header.